# Recently added a second section to my code and now it keeps stopping

Tags: python

After adding the second define function, the code stopped running. After entering an age, it just stops and outputs nothing afterwards.

```
def inputNumber(message):
   while True:
      try:
         userInput = int(input(message))       
      except ValueError:
         print("You did not type an integer, please try again!")
         continue
      else:
         return userInput 
         break 

def underage(message):
   while True:
      try:
         userInput = int(input(message))
      except ValueError:
         if age <= 7:
            print("Sorry, you are too young. Please get an adult for this.")
         elif age >= 100:
            print ("You must be under the age of 100 to continue!")
         else:
            return underage
            break

print("Welcome to my programme!")
name = input("Please enter a name you want me to address you by.")
print("Hello ",name)

print("How old are you" ,(name), "?")
age = inputNumber(" ")
age = underage(" ")

print("Great! You are" ,(age), "years old" ,(name), "!")
```

Should I combine both define functions into one? Code runs fine when the underage function is removed.

Comment: You can't convert a blank string to an integer.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote. However, @Abz, why ask for `age` in `inputNumber` if you are asking `age` again in `underAge`?

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions that seem to do the same thing.
Please remove on of them since you are reading 2 inputs at the moment:

```
print("How old are you" ,(name), "?")
age = inputNumber(" ") # <---- remove either this or the bottom one
age = underage(" ")
```

I will focus on the `underage` function.

You try-except block is suspicious. You receive input, and only process it if you have an exception? This is usually very odd.

Generally speaking exception blocks are used to catch an exception and either respond to the exception or propagate it.

```
def underage(message):
   while True:
      try:
         userInput = int(input(message))
      except ValueError: # <---- HERE
         if age <= 7: # <--- why are you processing if you caught an error?
            print("Sorry, you are too young. Please get an adult for this.")
         elif age >= 100:
            print ("You must be under the age of 100 to continue!")
         else:
            return underage
            break
```

I suspect what you want to do is only process if you *don't* have an error:

```
def underage(message):
   while True:
      try:
         userInput = int(input(message))
      except ValueError:
         print('please input an actual number')
         continue
      # we have a number, so keep processing.
      if age <= 7:
          print("Sorry, you are too young. Please get an adult for this.")
          return True

      if age >= 100:
          print ("You must be under the age of 100 to continue!")
          return None # why is this needed?

      return False
```

Now you have a function that returns what is expected, or `None` if it doesn't know what to do.

Some pointers:

- do not use `elif` unless it's really needed (very rare) it creates a lot of complexity in the code
- if you know what you're going to return, you return it immediately
- if your code does something unexpected it's best to give reasoning with a small comment (e.g. block people who are over 100 y/o)

Comment: `elif` is a perfectly good thing to use, and it's often the _correct_ thing.

Answer (score 0):

Lets's look at `underage`:

```
def underage(message):
   while True:
      try:
         userInput = int(input(message))
      except ValueError:
         if age <= 7:
            print("Sorry, you are too young. Please get an adult for this.")
         elif age >= 100:
            print ("You must be under the age of 100 to continue!")
         else:
            return underage
            break
```

Everything underneath `except ValueError` will only be executed if the user enters something other than a number. Change that to be like:

```
while True:
    try:
        userInput = int(input(message))
    except ValueError:
        print("That isn't a valid number.")
        continue
    if age <= 7:
        ...
```

Next, you have `if age <= 7`, but you're not defining or updating `age` anywhere inside your function. You probably mean that to be `if userInput <= 7`. Alternatively, change it to `age = int(input(message))` above.

Next, `return underage` returns the `underage` function itself. You probably mean `return userInput` (or `return age` if you decided to go that route).

Next, you don't need a `break` after `return underage` because once the `return` statement runs you're no longer inside the function.

But finally, you really want to combine those into a single function, like:

```
def get_valid_age(message):
   while True:
      try:
         age = int(input(message))       
      except ValueError:
         print("You did not type an integer, please try again!")
         continue
     if age <= 7:
        print("Sorry, you are too young. Please get an adult for this.")
     elif age >= 100:
        print ("You must be under the age of 100 to continue!")
     else:
        return age
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the second function, but the call to the second function *after* `age = inputNumber(" ")`.

I've reorganised your code somewhat, namely creating a 'main' function called `__init__()`, which is explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_class_init.asp).

Your `underage` function is called with `message`, and because you have [no class variables, or global variables](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp) - the variables you have created are not accessible from `underage`. Essentially they are out of scope.

A better way to organise (in my opinion) is like this:

```
def __init__():
    print("Welcome to my programme!")
    name = input("Please enter a name you want me to address you by.")
    print("Hello ",name)
    print("How old are you" ,(name), "?")
    age = inputNumber(" ")
    # age = underage(" ")
    while True:
        if age <= 7:
            print("Sorry, you are too young. Please get an adult for this.")
        elif age >= 100:
            print ("You must be under the age of 100 to continue!")
        else:
            print("Great! You are" ,(age), "years old" ,(name), "!")

def inputNumber(message):
   while True:
      try:
         userInput = int(input(message))       
      except ValueError:
         print("You did not type an integer, please try again!")
         continue
      else:
         return userInput 
         break


__init__()
```

Though this is still *far* from perfect, problems such as the `while True` loop need sorting out. Though this should help a bit.